# How to use JS variables defined in Razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following Razor code :

```
               @{
                    var villages = (List<string>)  @ViewData["allVillages"];
                }
               @if (villages != null)
                {
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        var villages = @villages;
                    </script>

                }
```

But when I want to use the variable "villages" in JS I get :

> ReferenceError: villages is not defined

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change @villages to @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(villages));. Ignore the syntax error and run the application.

```
 @{
    var villages = (List<string>)@ViewData["allVillages"];
  }
 @if (villages != null)
  {
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var villages =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(villages));
    </script>

  }
```

Please check. It worked for me.